# Add Route Parameter to all Razor Pages in an Area

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm trying to add a route parameter to all pages in a Razor Pages Area so every URL within an Area has an OrgId e.g. `/dashboard/{orgId}/{page}/{route}`. I can add them using the `AddAreaPageRoute` as shown below, but I can't help feeling there's a way to apply this to all pages without having to define an entry for every page in the Area. Is there a way to create a route for all pages in an Area?

```
.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Dashboard", "/Index", "Dashboard/{orgId}");
    options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Dashboard", "/AddItem", "Dashboard/{orgId}/AddItem");
    options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Dashboard", "/Items", "Dashboard/{orgId}/Items");
    options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Dashboard", "/Items/Index", "Dashboard/{orgId}/Items/{id}");
})
```

Comment: Hi @RichMercer,any update about this case?

Comment: Thanks, I'd looked at those docs but I think I'd turned myself inside out trying to figure it out I couldn't see the solution any more. Your answer works perfectly though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your code like below:

```
services.AddRazorPages(options =>
        {
            options.Conventions.AddAreaFolderRouteModelConvention("Dashboard", "/", model =>
            {
                foreach (var selector in model.Selectors)
                {
                    var c = selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template.ToString();
                    selector.AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel
                    {
                        Order = -1,
                        Template =c.Replace("Dashboard", "Dashboard/{orgId}")

                    };
                }
            });
         });
```

You can see the details in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/razor-pages-conventions?view=aspnetcore-5.0).